# sql query for many to one relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns

table: `StaffDepartmentAssgnment`

```
StaffId         DepartmentId          AssignedFromDate

S1              Dept1                 2013-02-08
S2              Dept1                 2013-02-08
S3              Dept2                 2013-02-01 
S1              Dept2                 2013-02-01
```

I want to find out all the StaffIds which are currently in Dept2.How do i write a query for it?

Comment: S1 is not in Dept2 now,he has been shifted to Dept1..i need to pick up the top AssignedFromDate –

Comment: Please add your comment to the question, using the edit button.

Comment: @Jodrell  yes the staff can be reassigned..and the corresponding date is inserted in AssignedFromDate..ne soln?

Comment: @PrachiPant: I don't know if you've realized that i've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812144/284240) according to the new informations you gave in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a DB engine independent solution

```
select * from 
( 
   select StaffId, max(AssignedFromDate) as adate
   from StaffDepartmentAssgnment 
   group by staffid
) x
inner join StaffDepartmentAssgnment y
      on y.staffid = x.staffid and adate = y.AssignedFromDate
where DepartmentId = 'dept2'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0ddf/3)

Comment: S1 is not in Dept2 now,he has been shifted to Dept1..i need to pick up the top AssignedFromDate

Comment: @PrachiPant, please expand on your comment in the question.

Comment: @PrachiPant: You can add a condition for the date. Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: i am using microsoft sql server..i guess none of the dates would be >current_timestamp..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sd.StaffId         
FROM StaffDepartmentAssgnment sd
WHERE sd.DepartmentId = 'Dept2'
```

**Update**

> S1 is not in Dept2 now,he has been shifted to Dept1..i need to pick up
>   the top AssignedFromDate

Since you're using SQL-Server you can use a `CTE` with the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT sd.staffid, sd.DepartmentId,
           rn = Row_number() OVER ( 
                    Partition BY sd.staffid 
                    ORDER BY assignedfromdate DESC) 
    FROM   staffdepartmentassgnment sd) 
SELECT staffid 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1 
AND    DepartmentId = 'Dept2'
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0ddf/11/0)